# gitignore - Ignore all file types except specified ones

Tags: git, gitignore

I only want to commit files which extension is `.fmb`, `.fmx` and `.pll`, but I can't configure `.gitignore` file to achieve this.

I've tried with the following:

```
!.fmb
!.fmx
!.pll
```

and also with:

```
!*.fmb
!*.fmx
!*.pll
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore) to make sure you removing the un-tracked files from the cache

Comment: I haven't done any commit yet, but I'll take into consideration for the future, thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your gitignore file-

`*
!*.fmb
!*.fmx
!*.pll`

You will want to first ignore everything and then whitelist files.

Comment: This will not work if any `*.fmb`, `*.fmx`, or `*.pll` is in a subdirectory.

Answer (score 6):

The only rule to remember when dealing with `gitignore` rules is:

[It is not possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20652768/6309) (`*`)
(`*`: unless certain conditions are met in git 2.?+, see below)

Since '`*`' would ignore folders as well, any file exclusion rule would not be working.

Try:

```
*
!*/
!*.fmb
!*.fmx
!*.pll
```

That will properly un-ignore the folders (`!*/`), and allow the next exclusion rule to work on files.

---

Note that with git 2.9.x/2.10 (mid 2016?), it might be possible to re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded [if there is no wildcard in the path re-included](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d589a67eceacd1cc171bbe94906ca7c9a0edd8c5#diff-7fea460d44f92f185e7add8aa5620305R144).

[Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds) is trying to add this feature:

- [commit 506d8f1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/506d8f1b394917c345965fc1762afa66678870c1) for git v2.7.0, reverted in [commit 76b620d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/76b620d8166bf4cc7cadbc61f9927799ceea9162) git v2.8.0-rc0
- [commit 5e57f9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5e57f9c3dfe7dd44a1b56bb5b3327d7a1356ec7c) git v2.8.0-rc0,... reverted(!) in [commit 5cee3493](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5cee349370bd2dce48d0d653ab4ce99bb79a3415) git 2.8.0-rc4.

However, since one of the condition to re-inclusion was:

> The directory part in the re-include rules must be literal (i.e. no wildcards)

That would not have worked here anyway.

Comment: @nathan the solution you have selected is wrong, and will not work when those files are in subfolders. Please don't mislead other git users.

Comment: @nathan I approve, this one is the correct answer, not the other. Please accept it.

Comment: This didn't work for me unless I removed the slash from the first line. I'm using git 2.14.1.